# PHP Jabber Integration

Tags: php, xmpp

I am wondering how to integrate jabber instead of using my AJAX polling script. I chanced upon the following: http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/

It gives me access to a jabber server, but does not tell me how to exactly go about it. I mean for example

$payloads = $conn->processUntil(array('message', 'presence', 'end_stream', 'session_start'));

Are there a fixed set of commands that I can use? Is there some site which explains the jabber workflow in very simple terms?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I am interested in this as well.  Thanks for the XMPPHP link.  It will be very interesting to see what answers there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two doc pages seem to be fairly readable:

1. [Core](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html)
2. [Instant Messaging and Presence](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html)

---

Also, you might already be heavily invested into xmpphp, but if not, you may want to take a look at [**Phurple**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phurple).  It gives you access to the [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) library (the code-base for [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/)) from PHP.

From the project page:

> This libpurple PHP binding, which
>   defines a set of internal classes,
>   gives a possibility to use aol and icq
>   (oscar), yahoo, msn, jabber, irc and
>   much more protocols directly from PHP.
>   Write your own IM chat client in PHP,
>   as simply as PHP enables it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been wondering about technologies to play around with XMPP, been looking at:

- [Strophe](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/)
- [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/tech/bosh.shtml)

Examples of this technology can be seen at:

- [drop.io](http://drop.io)
- [Chesspark](http://www.chesspark.com)